# Suma de Na resulta 0 en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Cuando sumo variables que contienen Na, el resultado es 0, y cuando la variable tiene valores 0, el resultado tambien es 0, cual es la forma de que cuando haya Na en la variable y no haya valores, el resultado sea Na y cuando haya 0 que el resultado sea 0.
Esto es algo del codigo que hice

```
df=data.frame(cod,dmy(fecha2),precipi)
  colnames(df)= c("codigo","fech","lluvia")

df <- df %>% 
      mutate(anio=year(fech)) %>%
      mutate(mes=month(fech))

df.anual <- df %>%
  group_by(anio,codigo) %>% 
  summarise(precip.anual = sum(lluvia,na.rm ="TRUE" ))

df.anual<-df.anual %>% 
  spread(anio,precip.anual)
```

el resultado por ejemplo para año 1969 es el siguiente:

[image: Resultado para df]

para todo el año 1969 las lluvias son NA pero en la suma anual en df.anual es la siguiente: (primer fila)
[image: df.anual]

Comment: Añade por favor un ejemplo, por que lo que comentas no es el comportamiento por defecto de R, normalmente es así:  `1+NA = NA` y `sum(1, NA) = NA`

Comment: Agregue algunas imagenes con el fin de clarificar el problema.

Comment: Si lo que dices es por el `summarize()`, estas usando `na.rm ="TRUE" ` que lo que hace es eliminar los valores `NA` de la suma. Si quieres que te retorne `NA` simplemente: `sum(lluvia)`

Comment: si realizo sum(lluvia) resultan todos NA, de esta forma para los años que tienen valores numericos y NA al mismo tiempo, imprime NA.

Comment: Si te entiendo, lo que quieres es: 1. Si un año solo tiene `NA` que el valor sumarizado sea `NA`. 2. Si el año tiene valores y `NA` la suma debería ser la de los valores sin los `NA`. Es así?

Comment: Correcto, eso exactamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La idea, sería:

1. Si todos los valores del vector son `NA` la suma debiera ser `NA`
2. Si No todos los valores del vector son `NA` la suma debiera ser la de los valores que no son `NA`

Conceptualmente la idea sería así:

```
todosNA <- c(NA, NA)
algunosNA <- c(1, NA)

ifelse(all(is.na(todosNA)),NA, sum(todosNA, na.rm = TRUE))
> NA

ifelse(all(is.na(algunosNA)),NA, sum(algunosNA, na.rm = TRUE))
> 1
```

Traduciéndolo a tu ejemplo:

```
df.anual <- df %>%
    group_by(anio,codigo) %>% 
    summarise(precip.anual = ifelse(all(is.na(lluvia)), NA, sum(lluvia,na.rm=TRUE)))
```